# Check if audio playing with Python on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, winapi, audio

I'm working with Python 3.7 on Windows 10. 
I would like to detect if there is any audio playing on my computer or not.
I was looking into `win32api.GetVolumeinformation` but I'm unable to get what I want.

When you control your audio you can see if there is a program playing and I want to achieve that.

[image: audio controls without program]

[image: audio controls with program]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python + winsound - check whether an audio file is being played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976364/python-winsound-check-whether-an-audio-file-is-being-played)

Comment: That dialog doesn't know, whether there is any audio playing currently. Open some media player, pause the playback, and hit the audio controls: No sounds is playing, but you're seeing your media player in the UI. So what are you *really* trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Unfortunately not, unless I've read it wrong that's about playing a file while I want to see if a program is playing audio.

Comment: IInspectable, my main goal is to create a script that will pause the program that is playing when I'm leaving my computer. So I'll have to use face detection. But before I dive into that I wanted to be sure that I can play/pause the audio if there is any audio. I already can play/pause the audio programmatically

Comment: I've found a solution using C# so I'm going to continue my project in C#. Is it okay to keep my question up in case someone else has the same problem or should I delete my question?

Comment: @metalbea If the issue solved you can post an answer and accept it. Maybe it will help other people are searching on this topic.

Comment: @metalbea hey could you guide me with what to look for in C# to accomplish this ? Thank you

Comment: @Alexandre Here is [my code](https://github.com/metalbea/MediaAudioChecker/blob/master/MediaAudioChecker.cs) for checking if audio is playing and to press play/pause programmatically

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently looking for the code to get the title off the image you posted above. Still helpfull thank you.

Comment: @Alexandre unfortunately I'm unable to help you with that. But I am curious to see your solution :D

Comment: I only got this for now, you need to have chrome running with a tab opened to youtube. This is the only drawback that I've noticed : Unformatted code, receives a process name, find it, enum the windows and check the titles to contain Youtube. \\\\\\\\ procs = enum_processes(process_name=processName)
    for pid, name in procs:
        data = enum_process_windows(pid)
        if data:
            for item in data:
                if processName == "chrome.exe":
                    if " - YouTube - Google Chrome" in item[1]:return item[1].replace(" - YouTube - Google Chrome","")

Comment: It's in Python 3

Comment: Also, if you wanted to get the title off the playing media, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011660/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-the-currently-playing-media-in-windows-10-with-python/66037406).

Answer (score 2):

Try this api using winrt:
The enum options are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control.globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssessionplaybackstatus), but you can use `mediaIs("PAUSED")`, `mediaIs("PLAYING")` ect...

```
import asyncio, winrt.windows.media.control as wmc

async def getMediaSession():
    sessions = await wmc.GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.request_async()
    session = sessions.get_current_session()
    return session

def mediaIs(state):
    session = asyncio.run(getMediaSession())
    if session == None:
        return False
    return int(wmc.GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionPlaybackStatus[state]) == session.get_playback_info().playback_status #get media state enum and compare to current main media session state
```

There are heaps more useful winrt APIs to control media on windows too [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control.globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssession?view=winrt-19041).

Comment: It's too bad this is missing a very important peice of info to get working. getMediaSession isn't defined and you don't menition anything about it.

Comment: Sorry. I have added the getMediaSession function.

Comment: Awesome. That's works great. Thanks for adding the missing code.