# How to check programmatically with python if any other application is playing audio/video

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, video, media

I need to check if any application is playing any kind of media. Most importantly I want my Python program to detect whichever application is playing audio.
The name of the application the audio is playing. And any related data are welcome.

I searched this up before posting here. I got many results, but unfortunately those are not for python. They were made for languages like C and C++.

My spec for your reference:

Operating System: Windows 10

Python Version 3.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python + winsound - check whether an audio file is being played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976364/python-winsound-check-whether-an-audio-file-is-being-played)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the answer you sent is not the answer for my question. Your answer is about playing music in the background. But the question I'm asking is about getting some info about the application that is playing the audio. To be precise for ex: when you open volume mixer in windows PC. It shows the list of Applications playing media. I want to make my program show that data