# How to check what audio is being played at the moment python

Tags: python, winapi, audio

I want to check what audio is being played at the moment for example
(i do not own this image) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHIgZ.png

I want it to print out what audio/song is being played.
There was a similar question to this but the solution wasnt working here.
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636713/check-if-audio-playing-with-python-on-windows-10) to check the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011660/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-the-currently-playing-media-in-windows-10-with-python looks to have a similar question/answer

Comment: @AlexV nope, didnt work

Comment: @Shashankh_ I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976364/python-winsound-check-whether-an-audio-file-is-being-played